# Need to add errored system to results in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a poweshell script to find all local accounts for systems in our domain.  It works fine except when a system is not available.  Then I get the following error:

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable.
At C:\Scripts\List-LocalAccountsAllSystems.ps1:11 char:17
+ ... ountlist = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $sys ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I have tried numerous ways to get these systems to at least have an entry in the csv even if it only contains the computer name but nothing works.  Here is all of the code.  Yes I know its messy and the csv is messy but in all honesty I don't care to much as this is all just busy work that they are throwing on us.  Another team will be looking a the results, not me.

```
$systemlist = (get-adcomputer -filter *).name

foreach ($system in $systemlist){

write-host "prcessing $system"

$accountlist = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $system -Filter "LocalAccount=True").name

foreach ($account in $accountlist){


    $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $System
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Local Account Name" -Value $account
    $OutputObj | Export-Csv -path c:\temp\localaccountlist.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation

    $account = $null
    }
    $system = $null
}
```

Comment: You need to place code that can fail in a try…catch block so that you can perform a different step if the WMI call fails. This script depends on every computer being online and reachable on the network. So really you need some type of state tracking so you can rerun the script until all computers are touched.

Comment: I have tried a try catch block and it works with the first system that errors but not any of the others.  is there a specific placement to the block?

Answer (score 0):

I found this script on GitHub,especially his try and catch is interesting for you, in handling computers which are not reachable.

https://github.com/lazywinadmin/PowerShell/blob/master/TOOL-Get-LocalUser/Get-LocalUser.ps1

```
function Get-LocalUser {

    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        This script can be list all of local user account.

    .DESCRIPTION
        This script can be list all of local user account.
        The function is using WMI to connect to the remote machine

    .PARAMETER ComputerName
        Specifies the computers on which the command . The default is the local computer.

    .PARAMETER Credential
        A description of the Credential parameter.


    .EXAMPLE
        Get-LocalUser

        This example shows how to list all of local users on local computer.

    .NOTES
        Francois-Xavier Cat
        lazywinadmin.com
        @lazywinadmin
    .LINK
        https://github.com/lazywinadmin/PowerShell
#>

    PARAM
    (
        [Alias('cn')]
        [String[]]$ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [String]$AccountName,

        [System.Management.Automation.PsCredential]$Credential
    )

    $Splatting = @{
        Class     = "Win32_UserAccount"
        Namespace = "root\cimv2"
        Filter    = "LocalAccount='$True'"
    }

    #Credentials
    If ($PSBoundParameters['Credential']) { $Splatting.Credential = $Credential }

    Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        TRY {
            Write-Verbose -Message "[PROCESS] ComputerName: $Computer"
            Get-WmiObject @Splatting -ComputerName $Computer | Select-Object -Property Name, FullName, Caption, Disabled, Status, Lockout, PasswordChangeable, PasswordExpires, PasswordRequired, SID, SIDType, AccountType, Domain, Description
        }
        CATCH {
            Write-Warning -Message "[PROCESS] Issue connecting to $Computer"
        }
    }
}
```